# The y-axis labels overflow on the y-axis

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

With this very minimal code of [Victory Chart](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-bar/),

```
<VictoryChart>
    <VictoryBar/>
</VictoryChart>
```

this is what I get

[image]

I'm struggling to put the y-axis labels off the axis.

PS: I'm using it with React Native

Comment: Did you try their `domainPadding` property?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf, the `domainPadding` param does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try this version. It's victory-native bug.

```
"victory-native": "0.15.0"
```